# Coroutine demo source /2

Tags: c++, coroutine

Can somebody explain why this code doesn't work on *codepad*?
A modified version (with virtual function) actually works though - 
Working version - http://codepad.org/5rRIg5zT
Not working version (below) - http://codepad.org/4PO2rBqS
I mean, is that actually valid C++, or codepad compiler is wrong?

Update: there's another working way to do this - http://codepad.org/j6GAKXov
but its not quite automatic.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>

typedef unsigned int   uint;
typedef unsigned short word;
typedef unsigned char  byte;

#ifdef __GNUC__
 #define NOINLINE __attribute__((noinline))
#else
 #define NOINLINE __declspec(noinline)
#endif

#include <setjmp.h>

enum{ 
  STKPAD=1<<16,
  STKSAV=1<<10
};

template <typename T> 
struct coroutine {

  volatile uint state;
  volatile char* stkptrH;
  volatile char* stkptrL;
  jmp_buf PointA, PointB;
  char stack[STKSAV];

  coroutine() { state=0; }

  NOINLINE // necessary for IntelC + my_setjmp.h
  void yield( int value ) { 
    char curtmp; stkptrL=(&curtmp)-16; // -16 is necessary for MSC
    if( setjmp(PointB)==0 ) { 
      state = value; 
      memcpy( stack, (char*)stkptrL, stkptrH-stkptrL );
      longjmp(PointA,1); 
    }
  }

  NOINLINE // necessary for MSC, to avoid allocation of stktmp before setjmp()
  void call_do_process() {
    char stktmp[STKPAD]; stkptrH = stktmp;
    ((T*)this)->do_process();
  }

  uint call( void ) {
    if( setjmp(PointA)==0 ) {
      if( state ) {
        memcpy( (char*)stkptrL, stack, stkptrH-stkptrL );
        longjmp(PointB,1); 
      }
      call_do_process();
    }
    return state;
  }

};

struct index : coroutine<index> {

  void do_process( void ) {
    uint a=1;
    while(1) {
      yield( a );
      a++;
    }
  }

} F1;

struct fibonacci : coroutine<fibonacci> {

  void do_process( void ) {
    uint a=0,b=1;
    while(1) {
      yield( b );
      b = b + a;
      a = b - a;
    }
  }

} F2;

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

  for( int i=0; i<20; i++ ) {
    printf( "%i:%i ", F1.call(), F2.call() );
  } printf( "\n" );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get a compile error with the one you've posted in this question. What do you get?

Comment: It works with gcc 4.3+/intelc/VS on windows, gcc 4 on iphone

Comment: Why didn't you just post a link to codepad with your code?

Comment: They're different here and on codepad. Codepad version has a virtual function which is inefficient.

Comment: Yes, that's why I was asking for the link to codepad with the code in your question, so we don't have to manually copy your code and paste it into codepad. Anyway, it seems like codepad's compiler doesn't like an incomplete type as a template argument, as far as I can see.

Comment: That's a question for the experts. When I use a class that has been declared prior, it works. (EDIT: I *thought* there was an easy work-around, but it's not that trivial because of the circular dependency between base and subclass. Gotta think about it some more.)

Comment: Yes, the whole trick is to call a method from child class without things like virtual functions

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" what happens?  Do you get a compiler error?  What does the compiler say?

Comment: Yes, compiler error - you can look at http://codepad.org/4PO2rBqS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the non-working version, if I change

```
struct index : coroutine<index> {
```

to

```
struct indexX : coroutine<indexX> {
```

then it suddenly compiles (using GCC). Apparently there is an 'index' already defined somewhere in a header file that interferes with the index of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, so here's a compact version which does work on codepad - http://codepad.org/6mBAyMhx

An interesting point is that it actually segfaults there without that *noinline*.

```
#include <stdio.h>  // for printf
#include <memory.h> // for memcpy
#include <setjmp.h> // for setjmp
template <typename T> struct coroutine {
  volatile int state; coroutine():state(0){}
  volatile char *stkptrH,*stkptrL; jmp_buf PointA,PointB; char stack[1<<10];
  void yield( int value ) { char curtmp; stkptrL=(&curtmp)-16; if(setjmp(PointB)==0) 
    state=value,memcpy(stack,(char*)stkptrL,stkptrH-stkptrL),longjmp(PointA,1); }
  __attribute__((noinline)) int call_do_process() { char stktmp[1<<16];stkptrH=stktmp;((T*)this)->do_process();return 0;}
  int call() {if(setjmp(PointA)==0)(state?memcpy((char*)stkptrL,stack,stkptrH-stkptrL),longjmp(PointB,1):void(0)),call_do_process();return state;}
};

struct Index : coroutine<Index> { void do_process( void ) {
  for( int a=1;; ) { yield( a ); a++; }
}} F1;

struct Fibonacci : coroutine<Fibonacci> { void do_process( void ) {
  for( int a=0,b=1;; ) { yield( b ); b = b + a; a = b - a; }
}} F2;

int main( void ) {
  for( int i=0; i<20; i++ ) {
    printf( "%i:%i ", F1.call(), F2.call() );
  } printf( "\n" );
  return 0;
}
```